# Add query params to an Icecast relay mount source

Tags: streaming, icecast

I am trying to relay a audio stream but besides the mount point /mount_source I need to pass query params so It would look like this:

`/mount_source?option1=a&option2=b`

Is there a way to do this? I tried specifying in my config file under   exactly what I described above but that does not work.

my exact setup is

`<relay>
        <server>stream.com</server>
        <port>8000</port>
        <mount>/fm?option1=123&amp;option2=456</mount>
        <local-mount>/localfm</local-mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>
        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>1</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
</relay>`

If i type in the address with the query options in the browser I will get the correct stream. But without the params I get a place holder stream which is basicly saying it is out of service. And that is what is happening in icecast too. It is getting the mount point but not passing the query options.

Comment: What happens when you do this (error.log output at Level 4)? What is the exact XML tag that you put into the configuration?

Comment: I updated my question